# PDFBox - on how to create a table view

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to display the set of records in rows and columns. Am getting output but the thing is, it is getting overlapped. should i modify the loop can someone pls suggest.

```
 for(j=0; j<Records.size(); j++)
           {
                Row<PDPage> row4 = table.createRow(100.0f);
                Cell<PDPage> cell10 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getIssueNumber());
                Cell<PDPage> cell11 = row4.createCell(45.0f, temp.getIssueDescription());
                Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getStatus());
                Cell<PDPage> cell13 = row4.createCell(25.0f, temp.getRemarks());
                }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but you may need to know that each beginText() sets the offset to (0,0), and that "newLineAtOffset()" is relative, not absolute.

Comment: @siva can you use boxable jar with pdf box , boxable is an compatible library with pdf box which can be ideal for your situation just refer following git repo which can provide more details on boxable jar for you https://github.com/dhorions/boxable.

Comment: For tutorials refer this link : https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/04/boxable-java-library-to-build-tables-in.html